# FsCheck integration with NUnit in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, fscheck

TL;DR: I'm not able to successfully use FsCheck with NUnit in C#: either:

- it tells me on stdout that the test failed but the test still appears green
- it tells me that it doesn't find any test to run
- or I don't understand how to apply in C# the doc I read

I think a dummy but complete example would help...

---

(More details)

**1st step: test remains green**

I installed the Nuget package `FsCheck.NUnit` (2.10.4), and naively tried:

```
[NUnit.Framework.Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    // Note the subtle bug: I Reverse only once, because I want the test to fail
    Func<int[],bool> revRevIsOrig = xs => xs.Reverse().SequenceEqual( xs );
    Prop.ForAll(revRevIsOrig).QuickCheck();
}
```

When I run it as I would run any NUnit test, it ends up green, even though I see on stdout that

```
Falsifiable, after 3 tests (1 shrink) (StdGen (2129798881,296376481)):
Original:
[|-1; 0|]
Shrunk:
[|1; 0|]
```

**2nd step: test inconclusive**

So I went on, found some [doc](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/RunningTests.html#Using-FsCheck-NUnit-with-TestDriven-Net), and noticed that I should use `Property` instead of `Test`. So I changed my code to

```
[FsCheck.NUnit.Property] // <-- the line that changed
public void SomeTest()
{
    Func<int[],bool> revRevIsOrig = xs => xs.Reverse().SequenceEqual( xs );
    Prop.ForAll(revRevIsOrig).QuickCheck();
}
```

I launched the test from Visual, and it ended up with the status `inconclusive`. And some log was telling me:

> Cannot run tests: No suitable tests found in 'xxx.exe'. Either assembly contains no tests or proper test driver has not been found

**3rd step: I notice I didn't understood the doc**

When I re-read the doc, I notice that it says that my test method can take argument and should return a property. I'm obviously not doing it since I return nothing.

The sad thing is that I don't understand what I'm actually supposed to do (and I'm not familiar enough with F# to understand the example below...)... (I've blindly tried some random stuff that looked they could make sense, but I never ended up with a red test)

I would really appreciate any pointer to help me get this test red!

Comment: Try `Prop.ForAll(revRevIsOrig).QuickCheckThrowOnFailure();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the `QuickCheckThrowOnFailure` function

> the `QuickThrowOnFailure` ensures that if the test fails, an exception with the necessary information is raised so the runner know the test failed.

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest() {
    // Note the subtle bug: I Reverse only once, because I want the test to fail
    Func<int[],bool> revRevIsOrig = xs => xs.Reverse().SequenceEqual( xs );
    Prop.ForAll(revRevIsOrig).QuickCheckThrowOnFailure();
}
```

Comment: Awesome: it works completely as I expected! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The other way to use FsCheck with NUnit (from FsCheck github examples) is

```
[FsCheck.NUnit.Property(Verbose = true)]
public void SomeTest()
{
    Func<int[],bool> revRevIsOrig = xs => xs.Reverse().SequenceEqual( xs );
    return Prop.ForAll(revRevIsOrig);
}
```

But this way doesn't report you why your test fails. So the Nkosi's answer now is better but I think it will be fixed somedays.

Comment: "from FsCheck github examples" Please could you share a link?

Comment: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/tree/master/examples/FsCheck.CSharpExamples
if still relevant

Answer (score 0):

Besides other mentioned options you can turn this test to a *Property Based Test* by using the `Property` attribute and correct return type (I've included namespaces for clarity).

Note the `.ToProperty` call to turn it into a `Property`.

```
[FsCheck.NUnit.Property]
public FsCheck.Property RevRev_IsOriginal(int[] xs)
{
    Func<bool> revRevIsOrig = () => xs.Reverse().Reverse().SequenceEqual(xs);
    return revRevIsOrig.ToProperty();
}
```

The framework will generate testdata via the `int[] xs` method parameter.

This requires *nuget packages* `fscheck` and `fscheck.nunit` (besides `NUnit3TestAdapter` and `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` in my `.NET Core 3.1` testproject).